# How to generate a Razor Page url within a custom TagHelper

Tags: asp.net-core, tag-helpers, asp.net-core-tag-helpers

I have a custom tag helper which should render something like this:

```
<ol>
  <li><a href="/my/razor/page/url">Some text</a>
</ol>
```

If I were to do this within a Razor Page I would simply do something like this: `<a asp-page="MyRazorPage">Some text</a>`

Is there a way to do something similar inside of the TagHelper?

Answer (score 3):

I found the answer.

Inject `IUrlHelperFactory` into the constructor as well as use the following property:

```
[HtmlAttributeNotBound]
[ViewContext]
public ViewContext ViewContext { get; set; }
```

Then you can create an `IUrlHelper` this way:

```
var urlHelper = _urlHelperFactory.GetUrlHelper(ViewContext);
var url = urlHelper.Page("/Clients/Edit", new { Id = myClientId });
output.Content.AppendHtmlLine($"<a href='{url}'>Edit</a>");
```

Answer (score 0):

TagHelper provides `HtmlTargetElement` to add attributes to specified tags. Take adding `asp-cuspage` to the tag `<a>` as an example. The method `Init` is used to receive the parameters in the instruction `asp-cuspage=""`. This method `Process` provides output attributes.

Create class `CusAnchorTagHelper`:

```
[HtmlTargetElement("a")]
public class CusAnchorTagHelper : TagHelper
{
    private const string CuspageAttributeName = "asp-cuspage";

    [HtmlAttributeName(CuspageAttributeName)]
    public string Cuspage { get; set; }

    public string Value { get; set; }
    public override void Init(TagHelperContext context)
    {
        if (context.AllAttributes[0].Value != null)
        {
            Value = context.AllAttributes[0].Value.ToString();
        }
        base.Init(context);
    }
    public override void Process(TagHelperContext context, TagHelperOutput output)
    {
        var reg = new Regex("(?<!^)(?=[A-Z])");
        string attr="";
        foreach(var a in reg.Split(Value))
        {
            attr += a + "/";
        }
        output.Attributes.SetAttribute("href", attr);
    }
    
}
```

Then, inject custom taghelper assembly into the page. And it will be drawn in the view.

[image]

This is the rendered result.
[image]

Comment: As noted in the question, I'm creating a TagHelper which spits out an html block, not just changes the value of an anchor.